# useTransition - Object is not a function or its return value is not iterable

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm running the experimental version of React to play with Concurrent mode and useTransition. The versions I'm running are:

```
"react": "0.0.0-experimental-27659559e",
"react-dom": "0.0.0-experimental-27659559e",
```

I've also made sure that I've opted for Concurrent mode from `index.js`:

```
ReactDOM.unstable_createRoot(document.getElementById("root")).render(<App />);
```

The component I'm trying to use `useTransition` on looks like this -

```
import React, { Suspense, useState, useTransition } from "react";
import { createResource } from "./utils";

const initialResource = createResource();

const UserInfo = () => {
  const [resource, setResource] = useState(initialResource);
  const [startTransition, isPending] = useTransition({
    timeoutMs: 3000,
  });
  const user = resource.invoice.read();
  return (
    <div>
      <span>{user.name}</span>
      <button onClick={() => setResource(createResource())}>Load data</button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Everything works fine until I implement the line with `useTransition`. The app breaks and throws an error saying `TypeError: Object is not a function or its return value is not iterable` highlighting the following line:

```
const [startTransition, isPending] = useTransition({
    timeoutMs: 3000,
  });
```

I'm not sure if there's an issue with setting up Concurrent mode. This is similar to what the official doc is saying for setting up `useTransition`. Can anyone give me some idea as to what might be going wrong here?

Answer (score 4):

You probably figured this out by now but they switched the values on us, it should be:

```
const [isPending, startTransition] = useTransition({
    timeoutMs: 3000,
});
```